# How to sort a generic Linked List

Tags: java, sorting, generics, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

The goal of this program is to read in any datatype from a .txt file into a Doubly Linked List, sort the data using bubble-sort, then print out the sorted data.

I can't seem to figure out why my compareTo function will sort Strings just fine, but when I try to sort int, double, or float the compareTo will only sort by the most significant digit. Here is my code written in Java along with my .txt file contents and program output.

Please I need all suggestions or answers I can get, because I am stumped!

Main tester class:

```
package test1;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
        list.readData("Test.txt");
        list.bubbleSort();
        list.printList();   
    }
}
```

Doubly Linked List class

```
package test1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DoublyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>{

private Node<E> head;
private Node<E> tail;
private int size;

public DoublyLinkedList(){
    size = 0;
    head = new Node<E>(null, null, null);
    tail = new Node<E>(head, null, null);
    head.setNext(tail);
}

public void add(E e){
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>(tail.getPrevious(),e, tail);
    tail.getPrevious().setNext(node);
    tail.setPrevious(node);
    size++;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void readData(String filename) throws IOException{
    E line = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while((line = (E)buff.readLine()) != null) {
        add(line);

    }
}
public void printList(){
    int i=0;
    Node<E> curr = head.getNext();
    while(i<size){
        System.out.println(curr.getData());
        curr = curr.getNext();
        i++;
    }
}
public void bubbleSort(){
    boolean sorted = false;
    int i=0;
    Node<E> curr;
    while(!sorted){
        sorted = true;
        curr = head.getNext();
        i=0;
        while(i<size-1){
            if(curr.getData().compareTo(curr.getNext().getData()) > 0){
                sorted = false;
                swap(curr);
            }
            curr = curr.getNext();
            i++;
        }
    }   
}
public void swap(Node<E> curr){
    E temp = curr.getData();
    curr.setData(curr.getNext().getData());
    curr.getNext().setData(temp);
}
}
```

Simple Node class

```
package test1;

public class Node<E> {

private Node<E> next;
private Node<E> previous;
private E e;

public Node(){
    this.next = null;
    this.previous = null;
    this.e = null;
}
public Node(E e){
    this.e = e;
    this.next = null;
    this.previous = null;
}
public Node(E e, Node<E> next){
    this.next = next;
    this.e = e;
    this.previous = null;
}
public Node(Node<E> previous, E e, Node<E> next){
    this.next = next;
    this.e = e;
    this.previous = previous;
}
public void setNext(Node<E> next){
    this.next = next;
}
public void setData(E e){
    this.e = e;
}
public void setPrevious(Node<E> previous){
    this.previous = previous;
}
public Node<E> getNext(){
    return next;
}
public E getData(){
    return e;
}
public Node<E> getPrevious(){
    return previous;
}
}
```

Here is the contents of my .txt file

```
12
123
321
2345
25
5423
2345
2
4
```

Lastly, here is the output from my program:

```
12
123
2
2345
2345
25
321
4 
5423
```

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` - yeah, don't do that. Java told you you were doing things wrong, and you told Java to be quiet instead of fixing things. `line = (E)buff.readLine()` - that doesn't actually do what you think it does.

Comment: You can't just cast a string to an integer, you have to use `Integer.parseInt`, otherwise, it will continue to use the `compareTo` of a string, because the value is secretly a string.

Comment: You also need to add `buff.close()` or use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), otherwise you will have a memory leak and possibly an unedittable file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it's *ok* to do this. First try to parse float, then int, and then String (At least i could sort as u wanted)

Please, correct me if i'm wrong.

#### FlowChart:

[image: FlowChart]

### bubbleSort:

```
try
{
    try
    {       
        float intCurr = Float.parseFloat ( curr.getData ( ).toString ( ) );

        if(intCurr - (Float.parseFloat ( curr.getNext().getData().toString ( ) )) > 0){
            sorted = false;
            swap(curr);
        }
        curr = curr.getNext();
        i++;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        int intCurr = Integer.parseInt ( curr.getData ( ).toString ( ) );

        if(intCurr - (Integer.parseInt ( curr.getNext().getData().toString ( ) )) > 0){
            sorted = false;
            swap(curr);
        }
        curr = curr.getNext();
        i++;
    }

}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    if(curr.getData().compareTo(curr.getNext().getData()) > 0){
        sorted = false;
        swap(curr);
    }
    curr = curr.getNext();
    i++;
}
```

### Test.txt

> 2 15 1
>   3.3 10 5 6 4 1 1 1 1 1

### Output:

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
>   3.3 4 5